# Is there a list of generic English sentences to practise translation?

Tags: resource-request, self-learning

I am currently learning a couple of languages (Welsh and Icelandic, among others) and am looking for some generic English sentences to practise my translation into other languages. I'm not particularly concerned about whether there's a list of correct answers, because I would like to use the same list to practise comparing from English into several languages.

Does anybody know where I might be able to find such a list online?

Comment: Can you add what you mean by "generic" English sentences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this site: [Tatoeba](https://tatoeba.org).  It's a collection of phrase translations between multiple languages. You can search for phrases:

1. in a particular language
2. containing a particular word
3. translated between selected languages.

You will have to assess the quality of suggested translations yourself, as translations are suggested by community volunteers.